# Manually set current user credentials in AWS Appsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, nativescript-angular, aws-amplify

I'm using Nativescript with AWS Amplify to login to AWS AppSync.

The session stored by Amplify is cleared after app refresh. I get no user from `Auth.currentSession()` after app refresh.

However, I store the jwt from login and can access endpoints manually by passing that in header.
I would like to use this to make Amplify believe that a user is logged in to use it in other parts of the application.

Is there a way to manually set credentials to use all the functionality of Amplify?

And how is successful login handled? How can I emulate the behaviour after successful login to set current session credentials manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possible way to this this as of now, however according to [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/1084) and [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/1035) issue on github, they have acknowledged this as a feature-request and are probably working on this.

The solution to my problem was to use the `nativescript-localstorage` module and assign `global["storage"]` to this module.

```
import * as storage from "nativescript-localstorage"
global["storage"] = storage;
```